# Posso dar new em uma classe dentro de um construtor de outra?

Tags: c++

Eu tenho duas classes: Trajeto e Trajetoi.
Quando vou dar new em Trajetoi dentro do construtor em Trajeto o programa não compila.Alguém pode me ajudar?

Construtor de Trajetoi:

```
Trajetoi(string Origem, string Destino, int passageiros) {

    this->passageiros = passageiros;

    if ((Origem.compare("Cascavel") == 0 && Destino.compare("Guaraniaçu") == 0)) {
        custo = CUSTO_CASCAVEL_GUARANIACU;
        Distancia = 76.2;
        tempo = 10 + 60 * 1;
        this->lucro = custo * this->passageiros;

    }

    if ((Origem.compare("Guaraniaçu") == 0 && Destino.compare("Laranjeiras do Sul") == 0)) {
        custo = CUSTO_GUARANIACU_LARANJEIRAS_DO_SUL;
        Distancia = 67.4;
        tempo = 5 + 60 * 1;
        this->lucro = custo * this->passageiros;
    }
    if ((Origem.compare("Laranjeiras do Sul") == 0 && Destino.compare("Cantagalo") == 0)) {
        custo = CUSTO_LARANJEIRAS_DO_SUL_CANTAGALO;
        Distancia = 35.2;
        tempo = 32 + 60 * 0;
        this->lucro = custo * this->passageiros;
    }
    if ((Origem.compare("Cantagalo") == 0 && Destino.compare("Guarapuava") == 0)) {
        custo = CUSTO_CANTAGALO_GUARAPUAVA;
        Distancia = 80.4;
        tempo = 20 + 60 * 1;
        this->lucro = custo * this->passageiros;
    }
    if ((Origem.compare("Guarapuava") == 0 && Destino.compare("Irati") == 0)) {
        custo = CUSTO_GUARAPUAVA_IRATI;
        Distancia = 104.32;
        tempo = 32 + 60 * 1;
        this->lucro = custo * this->passageiros;
    }
    if ((Origem.compare("Irati") == 0 && Destino.compare("Palmeira") == 0)) {
        custo = CUSTO_IRATI_PALMEIRA;
        Distancia = 73.5;
        tempo = 25 + 60 * 1;
        this->lucro = custo * this->passageiros;

    }
    if ((Origem.compare("Palmeira") == 0 && Destino.compare("Curitiba") == 0)) {
        custo = CUSTO_PALMEIRA_CURITIBA;
        Distancia = 82.9;
        tempo = 31 + 60 * 1;
        this->lucro = custo * this->passageiros;
    }
}
```

Construtor de Trajeto:

```
Trajeto(int n_Cascavel_Guaraniacu, int n_Guaraniacu_Laranjeiras_do_Sul, int n_Laranjeiras_do_Sul_Cantagalo, int n_Cantagalo_Guarapuava, int n_Guarapuava_Irati, int n_Irati_Palmeira, int n_Palmeira_Curitiba) {

        numero_de_passageiros_por_pedaco[0] = n_Cascavel_Guaraniacu;
        numero_de_passageiros_por_pedaco[1] = n_Guaraniacu_Laranjeiras_do_Sul;
        numero_de_passageiros_por_pedaco[2] = n_Laranjeiras_do_Sul_Cantagalo;
        numero_de_passageiros_por_pedaco[3] = n_Cantagalo_Guarapuava;
        numero_de_passageiros_por_pedaco[4] = n_Guarapuava_Irati;
        numero_de_passageiros_por_pedaco[5] = n_Irati_Palmeira;
        numero_de_passageiros_por_pedaco[6] = n_Palmeira_Curitiba;

        pedaco[0] = new("Cascavel", "Guaraniaçu", 1);
        pedaco[1] = new pedaco("Guaraniaçu", "Laranjeiras do Sul", 1);
        pedaco[2] = new pedaco("Laranjeiras do Sul", "Cantagalo", 1);
        pedaco[3] = new pedaco("Cantagalo", "Guarapuava", 1);
        pedaco[4] = new pedaco("Guarapuava", "Irati", 1);
        pedaco[5] = new pedaco("Irati", "Palmeira", 1);
        pedaco[6] = new pedaco("Palmeira", "Curitiba", 1);


    };
```

Queria saber se eu posso fazer isso... dar new dentro do construtor.
O erro que aparece é erro no new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, você pode. O problema é que você não está especificando o tipo de dado que você quer alocar memória.

Assumindo que

```cpp
Trajetoi pedaco[7];
```

Complemente seu código com o seguinte

```cpp
pedaco[0] = new Trajetoi("Cascavel", "Guaraniaçu", 1);
pedaco[1] = new Trajetoi("Guaraniaçu", "Laranjeiras do Sul", 1);
pedaco[2] = new Trajetoi("Laranjeiras do Sul", "Cantagalo", 1);
pedaco[3] = new Trajetoi("Cantagalo", "Guarapuava", 1);
pedaco[4] = new Trajetoi("Guarapuava", "Irati", 1);
pedaco[5] = new Trajetoi("Irati", "Palmeira", 1);
pedaco[6] = new Trajetoi("Palmeira", "Curitiba", 1);
```